# Behat stops running mid tests on a different test each time?

Tags: behat

I am encountering a bizarre problem with Behat where it will "randomly" just stop running even though it hasn't finished all the scenarios.

The strange thing about this is is that it will stop running in a different place each time which means it isn't our gherkin or php and must be something else causing it. This is running it multiple times without changes being made to any Behat related files or the website we're running it on.

Also, we do not get any output saying why it stopped running it just stops.

Anyone else experienced this and if so any advice?